# Studying Algebraic Logic from Plotkin's Universal Algebra, Algebraic Logic, and Databases.

Tags: logic, book-recommendation, algebras, algebraic-logic

I wonder what do you think about this book [Universal Algebra, Algebraic Logic, and Databases](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0792326652)?

I've looked for some reviews but found none so I can not determine if it's fine to learn about polyadic algebras and algebraic logic from or not.

I've tried to read some of the passages to figure out myself and found that it's sometimes tough and sometimes it seems good so I could not determine well. I wonder if someone has encountered this book, what do you think?

Does the fact that the main aim of the book is databases not algebraic logic   affect the approach which the author takes to algebraic logic? for example, the author mentioned that he has taken the viewpoint of a many-sorted algebras. How does this affect his treatment of algebraic logic? Does this make it easier or more difficult? How does this approach differs from the approach of mathematicians considers (I'm interested in how mathematicians view the topic not the applications' viewpoint)

Note that I'm quite familiar with basic ideas of algebraic logic. I've gone through the algebraic treatment of propositional logic in "Logic via Algebra" by Halmos(But not the final chapter on monadic logics) and I've read the first few chapters of "Models and Ultraproducts" by Bell  which proves Godel's Completeness theorem using Rasiowa's proof.

I know I've posed many questions here, but they are all related in a sense so I have no other choice to do this.